# Handling nested events

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a game that displays an archer and I am trying to set it up so that when my button is pressed, the user is then allowed to click anywhere on the screen and then a new archer would be set to where the click happen. My code currently allows me to click the screen and set a new archer regardless of whether the button was pressed or not. Could someone explain what is wrong becuase I though MouseEvent would occur on the scene once the button was pressed.

```
 myButton.setOnMouseClicked(
                    new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                    {
                        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
                        {
                            gc.setFill(color);
                            gc.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
                            scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                            {
                                public void handle(MouseEvent e)
                                {
                                    archer.setX((int)e.getSceneX());
                                    archer.setY((int)e.getSceneY());
                                    archer.drawCharStand(gc);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly are you trying to do? Do you the archer to be placed when the user presses a key on the keyboard and then clicks somewhere on the screen? Or do you want to clicks? The first mouse click activates the placement action and the second click actually places the archer?

Comment: The user should press the button, then after they have clicked a spot on the screen, the archer would be placed where the click occurred.

Comment: How about adding a variable that tracks whether or not the button was previous clicked and combining the above handlers into a single method?

Comment: how would I be able to combine them into one method? If i combine them into one method then would I would only have one EventHandler correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`ToggleButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleButton.html), so that you only place the archer when the toggle button is selected:

```
private ToggleButton myButton = new ToggleButton("Place Archer");

// ...

scene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
    if (myButton.isSelected()) {
         archer.setX((int)e.getSceneX());
         archer.setY((int)e.getSceneY());
         archer.drawCharStand(gc);
         myButton.setSelected(false);
    }
});
```

The last line will unselect the toggle button "automatically" after placing the archer. If you want the user to be able to place multiple archers easily (and have to manually switch off that mode), omit that line.

Comment: That works really well thank you! I didn't even know what a ToggleButton was so I am going to read the that link. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your code slightly. Perhaps try with a variable that tracks if the button was clicked:

```
boolean archerPlacementMode = false;
....
myButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    public void handle(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(!archerPlacementMode) {
                     archerPlacementMode = true;
                     gc.setFill(color);
                     gc.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
                     archerPlacementMode = true;
                      return;
                }
            }
        });

scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    public void handle(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(archerPlacementMode) {
            archer.setX((int)e.getSceneX());
            archer.setY((int)e.getSceneY());
            archer.drawCharStand(gc);
            archerPlacementMode = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it only moves the archer when I click the button and it moves in between where I click on the button. I think I have to have two EventHandlers because I need to be able to pick up clicks on the screen as well as the button.

Comment: yes, in that case you will need two separate event handlers - one for the button and one for the scene. Have updated the code for you.